# Create a macro to add new row that includes dropdown options

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row, dropdown

[What I start with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaDAh.jpg)

[This is what I want it to do, but for every row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TComq.jpg)

Here is the macro that was created when I simply copied and pasted the first row. This copies the dropdown menus for columns B and C, which I will need for every new row. So, it can't just copy the values that appear in the row being copied - it needs to include the dropdowns (the new row can be above or below the rest). Can the code below be tweaked to achieve that?

Sub AddLine()
'
' AddLine Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    Selection.Copy

```
Range("B5:C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("D5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("B5").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one approach. It copies the validation (only the validation) from `B4:C4` and pastes it one row below the `ActiveCell`. Presuming the cursor is *anywhere* in row 6, when you run this macro, the `Validation` dropdowns will be copied to cells `B7:C7`.

```
Sub CopyValidation()
    Dim rCopy As Range


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C4")

    rCopy.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: This gets the job done! I figured out something myself (clicked on "use relative references" when recording the same macro). But with your code, I don't have to be in the B column to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @TanyaChy Good to hear. Oftentimes, there are many ways to get to our answer, and it's all about figuring out the best one. It's good that you were able to solve a part of the problem on your own!